# SvelteKit does not set cookie returned from GET endpoint

Tags: cookies, jwt, sveltekit

I'm reformulating my question and code examples so it is easy to understand.

When I call this PUT endpoint, cookies are set correctly.

```
export const put: RequestHandler<Locals> = async (event) => {
  const userInfo = {
    refresh_token: Math.random().toString(),
  };

  const json = JSON.stringify(userInfo);

  const jwt = cookie.serialize("jwt", json, {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: "/",
  });

  const headers = {
    "Set-Cookie": [jwt],
  };

  return {
    status: 200,
    headers,
    body: {},
  };
};
```

When I call this GET endpoint, cookies are not set.

```
export const get: RequestHandler<Locals> = async (event) => {
  const userInfo = {
    refresh_token: Math.random().toString(),
  };

  const json = JSON.stringify(userInfo);

  const jwt = cookie.serialize("jwt", json, {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: "/",
  });

  const headers = {
    "Set-Cookie": [jwt],
  };

  return {
    status: 200,
    headers,
    body: {},
  };
};
```

This is the option sent to fetch, where method equals "GET" of "PUT" for each case:

```
  const opts: RequestInit = {
    method,
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  if (data) {
    opts.body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }
```

Comment: Could you instead try to set the cookie in the `handle` hook? https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#hooks-handle—`response.headers.append('set-cookie', jwt)`

Comment: But how would I send back the JWT to the hook handle from the endpoint?
Tried like this but had no success, PUT works, GET doesn't.

 const headers = {
    refresh_token: JSON.stringify(userInfo.refresh_token),
    "Set-Cookie": [jwt],
  };

Comment: I sent the JWT using the event.locals from the endpoint and it worked. Cookies are set correctly @kenset

Comment: Tested everything, all good. Thank you @kenset

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll write this up in an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cookie in the `handle` hook where it can be set in a single place for both endpoints. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#hooks-handle.

Pass the JWT to the `handle` method from your endpoint through the `event.locals` object.

e.g.,

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    const response = await resolve(event);
    response.headers.append('set-cookie', event.locals.jwt);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that something is still broken. Navigating through the entire site works perfectly, cookies are set correctly. But when I hit "Refresh" (F5, Ctrl + r), cookies are not set, it remains with the previous one.

And I can see from the response returned from the "handle" function that it is trying to set the cookie to the new one.

Comment: Would you mind opening a new question with the details? This feels like a different issue. In that question I'm curious to see what your `handle` method looks like.

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70914636/sveltekit-not-setting-cookie-on-page-refresh