# SvelteKit not setting cookie on page refresh

Tags: cookies, jwt, svelte, setcookie, sveltekit

Every request to my API has a retry in case it fails with 401. In that case, it generates a new JWT and returns it from the endpoint.json to the handle function by setting the "event.locals.user" with the new JWT.

This is my hooks file:

```
import { parse, serialize } from "cookie";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  event.locals.user = getUserInformation(event.request.headers.get("cookie"));
  const response = await resolve(event);

  if (isRequestFromEndpoint(event.request)) {
    if (shouldDeleteJwtCookie(event, response)) {
      response.headers.set(
        "set-cookie",
        "jwt=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
      );
      return response;
    }

    if (shouldUpdateJwtCookie(event)) {
      const jwt = serializeNewJwtCookie(event.locals.user);
      response.headers.set("set-cookie", jwt);
    }
  }

  console.log(response);

  return response;
}

function shouldDeleteJwtCookie(event, response) {
  return (
    isUnauthorizedResponse(response) && isRequestFromEndpoint(event.request)
  );
}

function isUnauthorizedResponse(response) {
  return response.status === 401;
}

function isRequestFromEndpoint(request) {
  return request.url.endsWith(".json");
}

function shouldUpdateJwtCookie(event) {
  return hasUserInfo(event) && isRequestFromEndpoint(event.request);
}

function hasUserInfo(event) {
  return !!event.locals.user;
}

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').GetSession} */
export function getSession(event) {
  return hasUserInfo(event)
    ? {
        user: {
          name: event.locals.user.name,
          email: event.locals.user.email,
          subscription: event.locals.user.subscription,
        },
      }
    : {};
}

function getUserInformation(requestCookie) {
  const cookies = parse(requestCookie || "");
  const jwt =
    cookies.jwt && Buffer.from(cookies.jwt, "base64").toString("utf-8");
  return jwt ? JSON.parse(jwt) : null;
}

function serializeNewJwtCookie(user) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(user);
  const jwt = Buffer.from(json).toString("base64");
  return serialize("jwt", jwt, {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: "/",
  });
}
```

Navigation between routes through the entire site works perfectly, cookies are set correctly when needed. The problem only occurs when hitting refresh, the new JWT cookie is not set, it remains with the previous one.

[image: Log:]

**Blue**: Normal route navigation
**Green**: Page refresh

So the problem is that the svelte handle hook is called two times. One for the "carteiras.json" endpoint, which has the correct event.locals.user jwt. And one for the "carteiras", which has the old event.locals.user jwt.

[image: Browser network requests when refreshing page]

It seems that when refreshing the page, the "carteiras.json" endpoint is called from the svelte server only, so it doesn't sets the cookie in the browser.

When doing normal route navigation the "carteiras.json" endpoint is called from the browser and then updates the cookie correctly.

[image: Browser network request - normal route navigation]

Comment: So it fails to delete the cookie? Does it make it past the `isRequestFromEndpoint` check and the `shouldDeleteJwtCookie` check?

Comment: Yes it gets past from both isRequestFromEndpoint and shouldDeleteJwtCookie and is correctly deleted, but only when it receives a 401 status (which is thrown after trying to call my backend API /refresh endpoint  with an invalid token). 

The shouldDeleteJwtCookie is irrelevant, I could’ve removed it before posting here.

Comment: Does it get past the `shouldUpdateJwtCookie(event)` check? Does `serializeNewJwtCookie(event.locals.user)` return a cookie?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions.

Comment: From what I can tell, you put the existing cookie into `event.locals.user`, then serialize a new JWT with `event.locals.user`—the cookie would have the same value. That's how I'm interpreting "it remains with the previous one" to mean — please help me understand if I am not getting it.

Comment: 1) I sign in, a jwt cookie (JWT1) is generated and set in the browser, and stored on redis 2) I delete the access token from redis, so when calling the api it will have to refresh the token 3) I refresh the page, api is called with the “JWT1”, but fails because it was deleted 3) the refresh endpoint is called and returns new JWTs (JWT2) 4) JWT2 is put into event.locals.user 5) a new cookie is serialized with the JWT2 and set into the handle response headers 6) I refresh the page again and my api is called with the old JWT1 (which is returned from the getUserInformation)

Comment: And all of this only happens when refreshing the page. If I do the same process but without refreshing the page, just navigating to another route that calls my api, all works. The “JWT2” is used correctly, if I delete it, a new “JWT3” is generated and used for new calls, and so on …

Comment: I have added logs and network requests. The problem is that when refreshing, the endpoint is called from the svelte server, so it doesn't set the cookie. Can't think of a solution...

Comment: Hi Camopy, did you get any solution or work around for this issue? When I refresh the cookie disappears.

Comment: No solutions yet, unfortunately